# Replace Information Link in a Report

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I created a report - RptBasics and saved it in spotfire library. The report is built on `Information Link` named `UserBasics`. I realized after creating whole report that it was to be built on `Information Link` named `CustomerBasics`.

Is there a way I can `change` only the `Information Link` of report instead of rebuilding whole report from scratch ? Alternately, can I duplicate whole report and change Information link at that time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both of your questions.

> Is there a way I can change only the Information Link of report instead of rebuilding whole report from scratch?

1. Open the dxp in the Professional Client
2. Click File > Replace Data Table
3. Select the Information Link you want to **replace** from the dropdown
4. Click Select > Information Link
5. Choose the **NEW / CORRECT** Information Link

> Alternately, can I duplicate whole report and change Information link at that time

When you save the dxp back to the Library, just save it as a different file name. Thus, you will have two versions... each with different datasources.